# IIF Conditional StartDate EndDate int/date collision

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use the IIF statements in SS-2012

I have this which works fine

```
SELECT 
       NULLIF(IIF( a.EndDate is null
                , DATEDIFF(MONTH, a.StartDate, getdate()) ,
       IIF( a.EndDate is not null
                ,  DATEDIFF(MONTH, a.StartDate, a.EndDate) , '')),'') 
       AS Months
      ,NULLIF(IIF( a.EndDate is null
                , DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, getdate()) ,
       IIF( a.EndDate is not null
                ,  DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, a.EndDate) , '')),'') 
       AS DateDays

  FROM
       TableDates a
```

The problem I came across is if the start date and enddate are on the same date(I am trying to default it to 1 month and 30 or 31 days whatever month it is)

I am gettiing

```
int is incompatible with date
```

When trying this below

```
   ,NULLIF(
    IIF ( (a.EndDate is null)  , DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, getdate()) ,
    IIF ( (a.StartDate = a.EndDate) 
          , DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, a.EndDate), a.EndDate),
      IIF ( (a.EndDate is not null) , DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, a.EndDate),'')

          )),'')
```

How can I default the days to 30-31 and month to 1 if the dates are the same?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Right now this is just "here's a bunch of headache-causing code, why doesn't it work?" Also, have you considered February? Leap year should be fun.

Comment: I'm trying to use `IIF` statements is not helpful. Why are you using them? Why not good old fashioned `CASE` expression? What is it you're actually trying to accomplish with this code? What datatypes are your columns?

Comment: The error happens because your `IIF` can return an `INT` (`DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, getdate())`) or a `DATE` (`DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, a.EndDate), a.EndDate)`). You can't return 2 different data types in the same column

Comment: @Lamak and a 3rd data type too (the fallback is an empty string!)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The DataTypes for StartDate and EndDate are 'date'.  I am just getting the diffs between a start date and enddate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh, right, didn't even got that far into the whole nested `IIF`s

Comment: @user1307149 As @AaronBertrand and I said, your `IIF` can return an `INT` (this happens when you do: `DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, getdate())`), a `DATE` (this happens when you do: `DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, a.StartDate, a.EndDate), a.EndDate)`) or a string (this happens when you do `''`). You are trying to return 3 different data types in the same column

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Sorry I was just using the IIF to see if they are good for dates or anything at all.  Funny page I just landed on is Aarons Page  Bad Habits to Kick  https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: @Lamak and Aaron thanks for pointing out the nonsense.  I know I can use other approaches.  I will revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show the number of days of the month as default where start date and enddate are on the same date then i hope the below query will work for you

```
IIF ( (a.StartDate = a.EndDate),
    (datediff(day, a.StartDate, dateadd(month, 1, a.StartDate))),...
```

and to show the month as default where start date and enddate are on the same date

```
IIF ( (a.StartDate = a.EndDate),Month(a.StartDate),...
```